# jquery tab load with dynamic href's

Tags: jquery, href, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm not sure if this has already been answered, but here goes

I have 4 tabs, two of which I load through controller calls; the remainder I'd like to vary the `href`s of and load automatically/on demand.

My problem is that even assigning a fixed `href` like "*www.google.com*" is not doing the job of displaying the remote page; and the two tabs with the variable `href`'s are properly being changed to the correct value, like so -

```
$("#anchor_ID").attr("href", "myURL"+var1)
```

where `anchor_ID` is the `<a href="..." id="anchor_ID" ....></a>`

but, these tabs don't load the content as expected.

Any points to check, what could be going on here? How much more info would you like for me to provide?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess jQuery UI Tabs doesn't support loading remote content (in the sense of remote == on different domain) via the simple unobtrusive ajax-style. You need to use an iframe as content of the tab for that.

If you check the tab "Local remote file" you notice that the url points to a file on "local" server. If that doesn't work for you you should post a sample to what `"myURL"+var1` really evaluates too.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#inline">Local local content</a></li>
        <li><a href="#remoteajax">Remote remote Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="localajax.htm">Local remote file</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="inline"><p>...</p></div>
    <div id="remoteajax">
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="600px" height="300px">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support/allow iframes</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this demo page

http://jsbin.com/uqile

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I did just that, after playing around with a few containers. However, since changing the src property of an IFrame itself depends on the site referred to and its responsiveness, I couldn't add any degree of processing pause messages ...

Comment: Is there anyway of displaying a "Processing..." message when the iframe src attribute is being retrieved? (jQuery, perhaps?)